# device_data.get() always return Null

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Hi I'm trying to get a token from a JSON format buy when I make .get('gtoken') they return NULL and i dont know Why

Here is my Code from Serializers.py

```
    class DeviceSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = (
            'gtoken'
            )

class AddDeviceSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField()
    device = DeviceSerializer()
    class Meta():
        fields = (
            'username'
            'device'
            )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Add Device to an user
        """
        device_data = validated_data.pop('device')
        user = User.objects.get(username=validated_data['username'])
        gtoken = device_data.get('gtoken')
        device = Device.objects.create(gtoken = gtoken)
        device.user.add(user)
        return device
```

This is What i'm sending

```
{
    "username": "735062",
    "device": {
        "gtoken": "cJHdNYxqIr4:APA91bFqFmFLoyf6t36iXAE9aoiSnG_nv8u5f6SfLVLrCtRYslAz04IZXfweLYg2RKRcQdJ6Vu0e9mLDFb2QB2k63oMnerKxSCfxO4PHmXrEQv_Pk-iWVlCsfoLYygat6OyPuiF79Gl1"
    }
}
```

The view only save the  device and It's working because the divice stores in the DataBase but without the TOKEN.

```
class UserDeviceToken(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)    
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,) 

    def put(self, request):
        serializer = AddDeviceSerializer(data = request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

NOTICE that the device is a model who has a user ManytoManyField relationship with Null=True that's why doesn't sent and error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `DeviceSerializer` to be a `ModelSerializer` since it has a `Meta` with `model` defined.

At the moment, it's a regular `Serializer` without any defined field. Therefore it doesn't return any data.

Comment: Man you're Awesome i didn't see that jaja :D Thanks jajjaa